# PowerShell script ONLY runs from within PowerShell, not as an argument to powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

Quite simply:

```
> powershell.exe -command "& '\\RemoteServer\c$\My Script.ps1'"
```

does not work at all.  `My Script.ps1` opens in Notepad, nothing more.  Meanwhile,

```
> powershell
PS > &"\\RemoteServer\c$\My Script.ps1"
```

works just fine (the script executes).

I did have to use the `caspol` tool, since my script relies on a binary module, but I don't see how that could be the issue.

Any thoughts as to the cause of this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
powershell.exe . '\\RemoteServer\c$\My Script.ps1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
powershell.exe -nologo -command "&{\\RemoteServer\c$\My Script.ps1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is the white space in your script name, here is a solution if you want to call from ***cmd.exe*** :

```
C:\>powershell.exe -nologo -command "&{$a=\"\\RemoteServer\c$\My Script.ps1\";& $a}"
```

`\"` prevent cmd.exe from interpreting `"` character

If you want to execute it into a ***powershell.exe*** command prompt :

```
PS C:\>powershell.exe -nologo -command "&{`$a='\\WM2008R2ENT\c$\temp\Aff le loup.ps1';& `$a}"
```

`$ prevent powershell.exe from interpreting`$` character

Hope it helps

JP